# C++20 ranges too many | operators?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, std-ranges

I am using g++ 10.2 for this code.  Does anybody know why I get a compiler error for the last `std::views::reverse` on `results3`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto values = std::vector{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    auto even = [](const auto value) {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    };
    auto square = [](const auto value) {
        return value * value;
    };

    auto results1 = values
        | std::views::filter(even)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::take(4)
        | std::views::reverse;

    auto results2 = values
        | std::views::transform(square)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::take(4)
        | std::views::reverse;

    auto results3 = values
        | std::views::filter(even)
        | std::views::transform(square)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::take(4)
        | std::views::reverse; // Error happens on this line.
}
```

Error snippet:

```
...
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:30:9: error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::reverse_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main()::<lambda(auto:13)> >, main()::<lambda(auto:14)> > > >' and 'const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&)> >')
   25 |     auto results3 = values
      |                     ~~~~~~
   26 |         | std::views::filter(even)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   27 |         | std::views::transform(square)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   28 |         | std::views::reverse
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   29 |         | std::views::take(4)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::reverse_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main()::<lambda(auto:13)> >, main()::<lambda(auto:14)> > > >
   30 |         | std::views::reverse;
      |         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                       |
      |                       const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&)> >
...
```

The full set of errors can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/Y7Gjqd

Comment: Interesting note: if you move the `transform` down past the last `reverse`, it compiles successfully. I'm wondering if the exact order of range adapters might somehow be conflicting either with CTAD or with concept constraint requirements. I'd be curious to know whether this is standard / correct behavior, or whether this is an implementation problem

Answer (score 35):

TL;DR: In this case, the iterator type of the result of `std::views::take` is `std::counted_iterator`, which sometimes fails to model an iterator concept when it's not expected to fail. This is [LWG 3408](http://wg21.link/lwg3408) and is resolved by [P2259](http://wg21.link/p2259).

---

This involves some really complicated mechanism.

Let

- `T` be the iterator type of `values | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(square)`,
- `R` be `std::reverse_iterator<T>`.

In the initializer of `result3`:

1. The iterator type of `... | take(4)` is `std::counted_iterator<R>`.
2. The `iterator_traits` for `std::counted_iterator<R>` matches the partial specialization `std::iterator_traits<std::counted_iterator<I>>`.
3. Said partial specialization derives from `std::iterator_traits<I>`.
4. `std::iterator_traits<R>` is generated from the primary template: it provides a member named `iterator_category`, but not a member named `iterator_concept`.
5. The `iterator_category` of `R` is the same as that of `T`.
6. The `iterator_category` of `T` is `input_iterator_tag`, because its dereference operator does not return a reference, which is not allowed by C++17 ForwardIterator requirements. (The `iterator_concept` of `T` is `bidirectional_iterator_tag`.)

So in the end, `std::iterator_traits<std::counted_iterator<R>>` does not provide `iterator_concept`, and its `iterator_category` is `input_iterator_tag`.

Therefore, the result of `... | take(4)` fails to model `bidirectional_range`, and thus it is rejected by `views::reverse`.

(The iterator type of `... | take(4)` is not a `counted_iterator` when `filter` is removed from the pipeline; the `iterator_category` is not `input_iterator_tag` when `transform` is removed from the pipeline. So `result1` and `result2` do not trigger this error.)

This is essentially [LWG 3408](http://wg21.link/lwg3408).

Comment: ... which will be fixed by [P2259](https://wg21.link/p2259)

Comment: @Barry regarding paper: is there some resource here on some other paper that describes what is the difference between C++20 and C++17 iterators? I presume some hacking/design was done to deal with ranges addition? All I found is this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator

Comment: so this is modern c++ huh?

Comment: @qwr if you can still understand how any of it works, it's not modern enough yet :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I don't. I thought I understood iterators, but now they're deprecated?

Comment: P2259 was voted into C++23. Herb Sutter has a [trip report](https://herbsutter.com/2021/02/22/trip-report-winter-2021-iso-c-standards-meeting-virtual/) about the latest C++ ISO standards meeting.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT** It seems that MSVC shows the same behaviour, so perhaps the conclusion in my answer is not correct.

I'd argue this is a bug in the implementation of the `take_view`.

Quoting from the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) page on the `take_view` (emphasis mine):

> take_view models the concepts contiguous_range, random_access_range,
> **bidirectional_range**, forward_range, input_range, and sized_range when
> the underlying view V models respective concepts.

Considering the following code we see the input to the take range is a `bidirectional_range`:

```
 auto input_to_take = values
  | std::views::filter(even)
  | std::views::transform(square)
  | std::views::reverse;

static_assert(std::ranges::bidirectional_range<decltype(input_to_take)>); // No error here.
```

However after passing that range into the `take_view` it is no longer a `bidierctional_range`.

```
auto t = take_view(input_to_take, 4);
static_assert(std::ranges::bidirectional_range<decltype(t)>); // Error (constraints not satisfied)
```

I'd argue this contradicts what is written on cppreference.

Now that the take view is not a bidirectional view, the following reverse view in your example can't compile as it expects a `bidirectional_range` as input.

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/88ofs3).

Comment: If this was the case, wouldn't the first two examples also fail to compile because they both use `take` before they use `reverse`?

Comment: Yeah, so this is why I assumed it is a bug in the implementation. That under some circumstances the bidirectional-ness of the input range get lost, under some others not.