# Why does views::reverse not work with iota_view<int64_t, int64_t>

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have the [following C++ program](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ehcj36vY), and for some reason I can not use `int64_t` as template argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template<typename T> 
void fn() {
    for (auto val : std::ranges::iota_view{T{1701}, T{8473}} 
                  | std::views::reverse
                  | std::views::take(5))
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    fn<int16_t>();
    fn<int32_t>();
    // does not compile:
    // fn<int64_t>();
}
```

Is this expected(I am doing something wrong), or is it just some unfortunate bug in compiler/std lib?

Note: when I remove `std::views::reverse` code compiles for `int64_t` also.

Comment: You can reduce the problem to https://godbolt.org/z/vzxWjzYqr and you get a soup of template errors. Curious!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/3PM7Wzz4q works with C++2b

Comment: You haven't included the definition of `int16_t`, `int32_t` and `int64_t`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++20 ranges too many | operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130679/c20-ranges-too-many-operators)

Comment: @GauravSehgal I would guess not, since although I do not understand that answer, I do not feel it explains the int16 && int32 vs int64 difference

Comment: Seems iota_view is flaky across compilers. This https://godbolt.org/z/1PoGTMEsY works with gcc but not with clang and it is the int32_t example.

Comment: Clang even fails to compile the example given on cppreference for how to use iota_view https://godbolt.org/z/1PjP6enqc https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a libstdc++ bug, submitted [100639](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100639).

---

`iota` is a surprisingly complex range. In particular, we need to pick a `difference_type` that is sufficiently wide for the type that we're incrementing to avoid overflow (see also [P1522](https://wg21.link/p1522)). As a result, we have in [[range.iota]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota#view-1):

> Let `IOTA-DIFF-T(W)` be defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, `IOTA-DIFF-T(W)` is a signed integer type of width greater than the width of `W` if such a type exists.
> - Otherwise, `IOTA-DIFF-T(W)` is an unspecified signed-integer-like type ([iterator.concept.winc]) of width not less than the width of `W`.
>
> [Note 1: It is unspecified whether this type satisfies `weakly_­incrementable`. — end note]

For `iota_view<int64_t, int64_t>`, our difference type is `__int128` (a wide-enough signed integral type). On gcc, `signed_integral<__int128>` is `false` when compiling in conforming mode (`-std=c++20`) and `true` with extensions (`-std=gnu++20`).

Now, in libstdc++, `reverse_view` is [implemented as](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e91a17fe39c39e98cebe6e1cbc8064ee6846a3a7/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h#L126-L133):

```cpp
template<typename _Iterator>
class reverse_iterator
  : public iterator<typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category,
                    typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type,
                    typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type,
                    typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::pointer,
                    typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::reference>
{
  // ...
  typedef typename __traits_type::reference reference;
  // ...
  _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR reference operator*() const;
  // ...
};
```

This isn't how `reverse_iterator` is specified. [[reverse.iterator]](http://eel.is/c++draft/reverse.iterator) defines the `reference` type as:

```cpp
using reference = iter_reference_t<Iterator>;
```

The difference is that the latter just means the type of `*it`, while the former actually goes through `iterator_traits` and tries to determine what `reference` means if `It::reference` doesn't exist as a type. That determination is specified in [[iterator.traits]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits):

> Otherwise, if `I` satisfies the exposition-only concept `cpp17-input-iterator`, `iterator_­traits<I>` has the following publicly accessible members: [...]

where `reference` is `I::reference` if it exists or `iter_reference_t<I>` if it doesn't. That looks like it's the same thing, but we have to first satisfy `cpp17-input-iterator<I>`. And `cpp17-input-iterator<I>` requires, among other things:

```cpp
template<class I>
concept cpp17-input-iterator =
  cpp17-iterator<I> && equality_­comparable<I> && requires(I i) {
    // ...
    requires signed_­integral<typename incrementable_traits<I>::difference_type>;
  };
```

So basically, `iterator_t<iota_view<int64_t, int64_t>>` satsifies `cpp17-input-iterator` if and only if `signed_integral<__int128>` holds, which is only true if we're compiling in `-std=gnu++20`.

But we shouldn't need to meet this requirement, since `reverse_iterator<I>` should just directly use `iter_reference_t<I>` and not go through `iterator_traits`, which side-steps having to check `signed_integral<__int128>`.